# Is it possible to use API keys, from javascript, in a Python model and then use the model in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, api, machine-learning

My plan is to use Python Machine Learning on an API key. By using that I will then use Tenserflow to translate that code into Javascript and start using my model there.

I don't know if this is possible and I don't know if you even can use an API key from Javascript in Python. So I tried to find answers on the web but with no hope.

Is it possible to use JS API in Python, if not then how could I?

Comment: An API key doesn't belong to one language or another, it's just like a passcode to access the API. It should be possible to access the API using any programming language...web APIs are accessed by making a HTTP request to the server. Almost every programming language has the capability to do that.

Comment: Ahh! Then you use the information from the request to build your model or have I misinterpreted the situation.

Comment: Well I don't know the specifics of tensorflow enough to know if that's the correct process, but I would assume you would do _something_ with the response, certainly. I was just commenting that your API Key ought to be usable in all programming languages, because the API server only receives details of your HTTP request, containing the API key as text (plus any other data you sent). It does not know how you created that request.